How to create a multiple form application in Delphi Firemonkey?
In Delphi 10.2. using Firemonkey for a Windows 10/11 desktop application, I want to create some sort of image manipulation application.
The main form of the application has a TImage that displays the image.
I use a second form with some controls so that the user can change some parameters of the TImage's bitmap. Any changes made by the user are displayed directly in the TImage.
The second control form is not always visible and should be non-modal.
I create the control form programmatically:
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle:=TFmxFormBorderStyle.Sizeable;
  WindowState:=TWindowState.wsMaximized;
 
  FControlForm:=TControlForm.Create(Application);
  FControlForm.Parent:=Self;
end;

This does not show the control form. So I tried to add FControlForm.Show;:
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle:=TFmxFormBorderStyle.Sizeable;
  WindowState:=TWindowState.wsMaximized;
 
  FControlForm:=TControlForm.Create(Application);
  FControlForm.Parent:=Self;
  FControlForm.Show;  //access violation error
end;

But this gives an access violation error.
What is the right way to do this?

Where do you call FormCreate from?

I call it in the TMainForm.OnCreate event handler. The program source is: Application.Initialize; Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm); Application.Run;

I can' reproduce your scenario. Could you please show us class definition your your TControlForm and its constructor code.

I can't reproduce the issue either. Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. That should include both form units and the corresponding .fmx files in text format.

I think the problem is that Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm) does not create the form.  From the help:

CreateForm does not create the given form immediately. It just adds a request to the pending list. RealCreateForms creates the real forms.

So Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm) is not the right place to construct the second form.
If you must construct the control form in this way, I'd suggest the following:
  procedure Loaded; override;
  procedure CreateControlForm;
.
.
procedure TMainForm.CreateControlForm;
begin
  BorderStyle:=TFmxFormBorderStyle.Sizeable;
  WindowState:=TWindowState.wsMaximized;
 
  FControlForm:=TControlForm.Create(Application);
  FControlForm.Parent:=Self;
  FControlForm.Show;
end;

procedure TMainForm.Loaded;
  Inherited;
  CreateControlForm;
end;

Loaded is not called until the form is actually created and loaded.
Alternatively, create the control form at startup, along with the main form, but set its Visible property to False (in the object inspector, at design time).  Then when you want to display it, set that property to True, or call FControlForm.Show.
